# Swing: How could I use JTree with JTextPanes as nodes?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jtree

`JTree` uses `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` as cell renderer.
This class is a subclass of `JLabel`.

I want to use `JTree` with more complex elements than `JLabel`, such as 
`JTextPane`.

Problem is: I can't subclass `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`, because it
would still be a `JLabel`.

Writing an own `TreeCellRenderer` is too complex.
Why? Because: `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` has 17 fields,
and does much more than just implementing `TreeCellRenderer`'s
`getTreeCellRendererComponent(...)`.

What simple solution can you devise?

I need the tree elements to be `JTextPane`s to be able to perform complex formatting.

Comment: What do you need the JTextPane for?

Comment: Gonna have to implement the interface. Shouldn't be too hard. Actually, I find it fun to mess with gui stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class JTextPaneTreeCellRenderer extends JTextPane implements TreeCellRenderer {
```

Method:

```
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {

    // do stuff to this instance of JTextPane
    setEditable(selected);
    setText(value.toString()); //Assumes whatever you stuck in the tree has pretty toString

    if (leaf)
        setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    return this;
}
```

You don't need to be as complex as the default implementation.  Making the Renedere a subclass of `JTextPane` will make the implementation of the method much easier.

Comment: you could also argue that it would also be 'cleaner' to do it this way.

Comment: @jjnguy Can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/q/51913716/7339033

Answer (score 0):

You could still subclass DefaultTreeCellRenderer and override just the `getTreeCellRendererComponent` method to return the `JTextPane` component formatted as you would like it.  You would still need to do a lot of the stuff that DefaultTreeCellRenderer does in its implementation, but you would not have to bother with the maintenance aspect of those 17 or so fields.

**edit** removed the JTextField editor solution after reading comments

Comment: No, that's cell editor. For this, there is a nice abstract class AbstractCellEditor